# Using nvD3' Throwing error while building for android platform

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ng2-nvd3 module for graph.it is working for ionic serve command and not working when building app for android platform

```
Error: Unexpected value 'nvD3' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```